# How to enable pretty-printing when using the Visual Studio Code 'Makefile' extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, makefile, pretty-print

I am using VS Code for a C++ project in Linux.  It has a Makefile, so I enabled the Makefile extension ([https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/now-announcing-makefile-support-in-visual-studio-code/][1]](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/now-announcing-makefile-support-in-visual-studio-code/%5D%5B1%5D) in VS Code.

I can successfully build, debug and execute.  However, I cannot figure out how to automatically enable pretty printing when I debug using the Makefile extension.  My 'launch.json' file does have the

```
  "setupCommands": [
    {
      "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
      "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
      "ignoreFailures": true
    }
  ],
```

However, the Makefile extension seems to ignore those settings.  Instead it appears that it has its own settings.json file with a part of it being the below, but it does not accept `setupCommands` as above:

```
  "makefile.launchConfigurations": [
    {
      "cwd": "/path/to/bin",
      "binaryPath": "/path/to/executable",
      "binaryArgs": []
    }
  ],
```

Comment: ?? Makefiles don't debug.  Makefiles make things (compile programs etc.).  Debuggers debug.  You want to configure your debugger (say, GDB).

Comment: @MadScientist:  This question is on configuring the "Makefile Extension" that Microsoft supplies for Visual Studio Code.  That extension allows me to build, debug, and run.  When I use it to debug, I cannot figure out the configuration to allow -enable-pretty-printing.

Comment: @MarcMeketon did you ever figure this out? I'm unable to get pretty-printer working with the Makefile extension as well (it works with file-based compilation)

Comment: @mark - sadly, no.